# CSS Grid with cross pattern

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid with a cross pattern.

So far so good, but I'm struggeling to get the crosses on the outside of the div.

In the example you can see the outside crosses are "flat", I'd like to have them exact the same as on the inside (= a full cross).

**edit: By flat i mean they are not a full cross. Either they are a corner or half a cross.**

Anyone has an idea?

My pen:

https://codepen.io/twohundred/pen/OJoObXw

```
<div class="container">
<div class="grid">
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { 
    background-color: red; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
} 

.container { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 101px;
}

.grid > div {
    position: relative;
}

/* Bottom right */
.grid > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.grid > div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.grid > div > div {
    height: calc(100% - 1rem);
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(5n - 4) > div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(5n - 5) > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

/* Top row top right */
.grid > div:nth-child(-n + 5) >div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.grid > div:nth-last-child(-n + 4) > div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: By flat i mean they are not a full cross.
Either they are a corner or half a cross

Comment: your cross is 1rem width and height. you have in absolute position with left -1px, top -1px, bottom 0 and right 0 (regarding its nth-child number). Meaning border is on the edge, no room for the 1rem on first left, last right, first top line, last bottom line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it using one pseudo element and gradients. The trick is to have an overlap between all the pseudo element and don't forget to consider the gap on the grid to make the calculation easy.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  padding: 2em;
}

.grid {
  --w: 25px; /* width of the line */
  --s: 1px;  /* thickness of the line */
  --c: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  gap: var(--s);
}

.grid > * {
  position: relative;
}
.grid > *:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  inset: calc((var(--s) + var(--w))/-2);
  background:
    conic-gradient(at var(--s) var(--w),#0000 75%,var(--c) 0)
     calc((var(--w) - var(--s))/2) 0,
    conic-gradient(at var(--w) var(--s),#0000 75%,var(--c) 0)
     0 calc((var(--w) - var(--s))/2);
  background-size: calc(100% - var(--w)) calc(100% - var(--w));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't have put it better myself ... very insightful, thank you!